# How to synchronise separate animations in AnimationSet?

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a mapFragment on which I am applying an animation set. The effect I am looking for is the following - "breathing" animation. The individual circles are expanding and fading doing so:

[image]

The current animation code does that:

[image]

That looks a bit not synchronised. Is there any way how I can achieve more synchronised effect?

Current code:

```
...
private AnimationSet breadingAnimations;


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    breadingAnimations = new AnimationSet(true);
    breadingAnimations.restrictDuration(3000);
    breadingAnimations.setStartOffset(500);

}
...
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;


//Add smallest image drawable overlay

        Bitmap mDotMarkerBitmap1 = generateBitmapFromDrawable(R.drawable.circle_drawable);

        GroundOverlay groundOverlay1 = mMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
                .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(mDotMarkerBitmap1))
                .position(xDesign, 100));

        groundAnimation = new RadiusAnimation(groundOverlay1);
        groundAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        groundAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
        //        groundAnimation.setDuration(700);
        breadingAnimations.addAnimation(groundAnimation);


        Bitmap mDotMarkerBitmap2 = generateBitmapFromDrawable(R.drawable.circle_drawable2);
        GroundOverlay groundOverlay2 = mMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
                .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(mDotMarkerBitmap2))
                .position(xDesign, 100));

        Animation groundAnimation2 = new RadiusAnimation(groundOverlay2);
        groundAnimation2.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        groundAnimation2.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
        //        groundAnimation2.setDuration(900);
        breadingAnimations.addAnimation(groundAnimation2);


        Bitmap mDotMarkerBitmap3 = generateBitmapFromDrawable(R.drawable.circle_drawable3);
        GroundOverlay groundOverlay3 = mMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
                .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(mDotMarkerBitmap3))
                .position(xDesign, 100));
        Animation groundAnimation3 = new RadiusAnimation(groundOverlay3);
        groundAnimation2.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        groundAnimation2.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
        //        groundAnimation2.setDuration(1100);
        breadingAnimations.addAnimation(groundAnimation3);

        mapFragment.getView().startAnimation(breadingAnimations); // start animation
```